# First and second largest amount

Tags: java

The problem is :

> Write a program that prompt the user to enter 5 numbers and find the
>   two largest values among them. If the user enters number more than 100
>   or less than – 100 the program should exit.
>
> ```
> Hint: use break.
> ```

My code is :

```
import java.util.*;

public class q2 {
    static Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    public static void main (String[] args ) {

        int num;
        int max=0;//define Maximum value and save it in variable max = 0;
        int secondMax=0;//define the second maximum value and save it in variable secondMax = 0;

        System.out.println("Please , Enter 5 numbers between 100 and -100 "); //promet user to enter 5 numbers with the condition

        for (int count=0 ; count<5 ; count++) // start loop with (for) 
        {
            num = scan.nextInt();//user will enter number it will be repeated 5 times .

            if( num > 100 || num<-100) //iv the user enter a number less than -100 or geater than 100 program will quit from loop
            {
                System.out.println("The number you have entered is less than -100 or greater than 100 ");//telling the user what he did
                break;//End the loop if the condition ( num > 100 || num<-100) is true .
            }
            if(num>max )//Another condition to find the maximum number
                max = num;//if so , num will be saved in (max)

            if (num >= secondMax && num < max)// A condition to find the second Maximum number
                secondMax = num;//And it will be saved in (secondMax)
        }//End loop
        System.out.println("The largest value is " + max); //Print the largest number
        System.out.println("The second largest value is " + secondMax );//print the second largest number .
    }//End main

}//End class
```

This is what my code outputs:

```
Please , Enter 5 numbers between 100 and -100 
20
30
60
20
-10
The largest value is 60
The second largest value is 20
```

The second largest number is incorrect - 20, not 30. What did I do wrong?

Comment: You lose 30 because it is substituted with 60 and not copied over to `secondMax`. I guess, you should add this to first `if` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 if(num>max )//Another condition to find the maximum number
 secondMax = max;
  max = num;//if so , num will be saved in (max)

 else if (num >= secondMax)// A condition to find the second Maximum number
 secondMax = num;//And it will be saved in (secondMax)
```

Answer (score 4):

There can be two cases,

1. You find new max, in this case, update secondmax and set this num as max
2. You find new SecondMax, update only secondmax

Try this

```
if(num>secondMax&&num<max)   // case 2
{
    secondMax = num
} 
else if(num>max)   // case 1
{
    secondMax = max;
    max = num;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you replace the highest number by one that is even higher, the former largest one becomes the second largest (becaus it'S still larger than the former second largest). Your code doesn't reflect that.
Everytime you change the largest nubmer, set the second largest to the old largest one.

Answer (score 0):

In the condition where the max number change first save previous max than assign new max otherwise second max should be adjusted if it less than the number.

```
if(num>max ){//Another condition to find the maximum number
   secondmax = max;
   max = num;//if so , num will be saved in (max)
} else if (num > secondmax) {
   secondmax = num;
}
```

Comment: Wont work, if max = 9 and secondmax = 8 and the new number is 10, your code would generate 10 and 8 as max and secondmax, which ofcourse is wrong

Comment: @AnkitRustagi Nope, it will output 60,30

Comment: Great so now you have max = 60, secondmax = 30 and i add 40 to the list of numbers. would your code still work ?

Comment: @AnkitRustagi yes, you're right the 40 should be checked additionally, but that was not in the input list, so could be omitted.